# Sailsjs 1.0 and mongo adapter aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, sails.js, waterline

I'm trying to perform an aggregate query that uses the $dateToString aggregation function but whenever I execute it i get the following error:

```
can't convert from BSON type string to Date
```

Note that if I execute the query through any client the query perfectly answers with expected result: a counter for each day.

My code is the following:

```js
getResultsDashboard: async function (req, res) {
    var db = myTestCollection.getDatastore().manager;
    var rawmyTestCollection = db.collection(myTestCollection.tableName);

    let aggregateQuery = [
      {
        $match: { field1: "myValue" },
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$createdAt" } },
          count: { $sum: 1 },
        },
      },
      {
        $sort: { _id: -1 },
      },
    ];

    let resultsByDate = await rawmyTestCollection.aggregate(aggregateQuery).toArray();

    return res.json(resultsByDate);
  }
```

I've also tried with native instead

```js
    myTestCollection.native((err, coll) => {
      coll.aggregate(aggregateQuery).toArray((err2, result) => console.log(result));
    });
```

But no results, only a message of deprecation for the native method.

I guess it is the driver for mongo.
Is there any other driver for sails? Or how can I implement the query in other way? Except, of course, getting from the db all the dates and then performing all the aggregation in javascript.

Comment: Do you have a sample document? Are you sure the value of that field isn't already a string?

Comment: It's date for sure. If i execute the query through any client it works perfectly. I'll add to the question.